# Data rendering is making animation lag

Tags: javascript, frameworks, angularjs

We are currently use Angular.js for our application and we need to add animation. We create directive that help us with that.

But the main problem is that if I start an animation at the same time as angular update the model and render it in the view, my animation start lagging. The problem occur only when I have big list (around 150) created by ng-repeat.

I've tried to use jquery animation and TweenMax but it doesn't change a thing. I really need help to fix that because one of our biggest problem right now is the performance of our application with the animation.

Anyone have an idea how to prevent that?

I'm not doing that much in my code:

```
**In crontroller**

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function( obj, current, previous ){
    aciData.getSequence( $scope.sequenceSlug ).then(function(data) {
        $rootScope.sequence = data.data;    
    });
}

**In directive**
scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function( obj, current, previous ){ 

    if(angular.isDefined(current.params.sequence) && current.params.sequence != 'dashboard'){
        elm.animate({
             'left' : '0'
            });
        } else {
            elm.animate({
                'left' : -elm.outerWidth()
            });
        }           

    })
```

I may not be able to use the latest build of angular with animation since it's still unstable.

Comment: This will be very difficult to answer without some code, but in general you need to look into restricting watches/digests and probably using a different animation method. For reference, the latest version of Angular also has several ways to do animation cleanly. See http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate and the source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/0b6f1ce5f89f47f9302ff1e8cd8f4b92f837c413 for some more tips.